# Allow some special character along with alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, regex

I have used php `preg_replace` function to allow only alphanumeric character from a variable string. The code is given below. This code works fine.

But now I want to allow some special characters like`~!@#$%^&*()_+/` etc along with alphanumeric characters. How to do this?

```
$hashh=$_GET['hash'];
$hash = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $hashh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$regex = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_+\/]+/";
$string = "Th3 4ll0w3d P4rt5 4r3 ~!@#$%^&*()_+/";
$preg = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
echo $preg;
```

Comment: can i use this for preg_match also?

Comment: Of course, The `^` in the beginning of `[]` means `Not` So for `preg_match` you can just remove it and it would be `Only` as `/[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_+\/]+/`

Comment: is it ok  else if(!preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_+\/]+/", $cpass))
 {
  $error = "Not valid Password !";
  $code = 3;
 }

Comment: @John why would you use `else if`? But yes, `if (!preg_match())` means if it doesn't match the following `RegEx` and since it is `/[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_+\/]+/` which can be translated into 'If it is made of Only alphanumeric characters and these special characters'